# Android - Draw mesh of images and attach touch listeners to individual elements

Tags: android, canvas, draw, gesture, ontouchlistener

I am having a bit of trouble with the following scenario for an android app. My requirements will be,

1. Draw a mesh of images on screen. I am trying to use canvas class for
   drawing images.
2. Draw a line between all these images and make a mesh.
3. Include touch listeners to these individual elements in mesh.
4. Include pinch zoom gesture in mesh to add new elements dynamically.
   This means, mesh will have to re-align and again make connections to
   every image element made.

I am bit desperate with this problem. Can anybody help please.

Comment: are you looking for this https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

Comment: @GopalRao Thanks for the reply. But this seems to not be what I am looking for. My mesh should look like a solar system (not exactly a grid where distance between adjacent elements will be same) , and there will be connector lines in between each and every element.